# Token Tracker (list of all token)

Tags: tokens

Do I have some questions:

1. Do I right understand that [list](https://etherscan.io/tokens) contains all tokens of standard ERC-20? Or this list is not full?
2. Can the token be sent to Ethereum addresses (for example 0xd4dd25e3995cB76a0C82bD305fB10A1bC0870316) from Exchanges (for example Binance) via standard ERC-20?

Sorry, it may be a silly question. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The list that you mention it's the tokens that verified by etherscan team as the original token with full profile details for avoid scam tokens.

2- Yes, this is the system in force on the Ethereum network, as for the Binance network, the applicable name is BEP20.

Comment: 2. As I understand I have to use BEP20 in Binance to withdraw tokens to Ethereum addresses (not  ERC-20). ERC-20 - only Ethereum coins, BEP-20 - only for tokens. Do I right understand?

Comment: Yes, they are two different networks.

Comment: I'm confused at all. Let's see the address 0xd4dd25e3995cB76a0C82bD305fB10A1bC0870316 it belongs to Ethereum network blockchain. It has tokens how we can see in the blockchain. And I have a question how is it possible? If you say ERC-20 - use only the Ethereum coin. How the owner of that wallet can send himself a token and keep it. As I understand Binance network blockchain and Ethereum network blockchain are different and wallets/addresses are different too.

Comment: Binance and Ethereum share the same network architact and solidity(Programing lang) for that the both networks and the same reason that he owns himself for the same wallet address (mean same privetkey) on both networks, the main defrent thing is the ledger (Transactions,Blocks) for that you do not find the same tokens on both networks because each network has its own ledger and its main currency.
With regard to sending itself, the matter is normal because the network and the ledger in every transfer has an entrance and an output, and in the transfer process, the sender is the receiver.

Comment: Yes, you're right. They both are built the same network architecture. But as I understand now if I want to get a token in the Ethereum wallet I have to send it via ERC-20, and if I want to get a token in the Binance wallet I have to send it via BEP-20 or BEP-2.

Comment: The first case when I send via Ethereum I get my token at Ethereum address (like 0xd4dd25e3995cB76a0C82bD305fB10A1bC0870316). Although both networks have similar address structures they belong to different networks. And for example, if the Binance network would have another type of private keys encrypting and we would send tokens to Binance (BEP-20 instead of ERC-20) wallet then we would lose this token. Do I right understand all things?

Comment: I see addresses at Binance Chain Explorer. They are not the same as ETH addresses (fo ex. address in BSC: Bbnb1r3sd3v9slkjvm95ct3pqgqrnvcr5v9yldpqwpv) - https://explorer.binance.org/address/bnb1r3sd3v9slkjvm95ct3pqgqrnvcr5v9yldpqwpv. I thought that the BSC and ETH are two different networks with the same addresses. But how we can see itès not true. I'm confused again at all. :-(

Comment: there is two different chain on binance the first one is "BINANCE CHAIN" this is have unique chain development "non-smart contract " and the name of tokens is BEP2 and address exmpel "bnb1akey87kt0r8y3fmhu2l8eyzdjvt9ptl5cppz0v", and second one is copy of Ethereum development chain and its name "Binance Smart Chain"  and this blockchain we have ability to deploy the smart contacts as Ethereum and the name of tokens is BEP20.

Comment: I see now. Thanks... I think I have the last question to get the whole information for now. Does the BSC have its own blockchain or It use Ethereum blockchain?

Comment: It is a copy of the system have its own ledger.

Comment: Ledger? What is it? Is it another name of blockchain?